# Need help understanding why my fetch method is sending undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As the title says my fetch isn't doing what I want it to. Im trying to implement stripe into my grocery store website. I'm using a node.js server with express, and ejs to integrate with the front end. My client side js uses a fetch method to send a POST request to the server with all the information from the client side. The client side pulls data from a JSON file to access the store items. Those items are to be restructured as objects in the fetch and sent to the server to initiate the stripe checkout.

However, the fetch fails at the get go with a status 500. It claims that an unidentified was passed instead of a JSON. As a result, I tried to send back a hard coded object to see where the error was occurring but it also came back as undefined. I'm stumped and need any help I can get.
I'm new at coding/programming so I'm sure there is a lot wrong with my code. Thank you for your time. My code is below.

Client side JS

```
let payButton = document.getElementsByClassName("pay")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  // alert("Payment recieved");
  // let totalItemsInCart = document.getElementsByClassName("shopping-cart-item-div");
  //
  // let x = 0;
  //
  // while (x < totalItemsInCart.length){
  //   totalItemsInCart[x].remove();
  // }
  // updateCartTotal();

  let items = [];
  let cartCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("shopping-cart-basket")[0];
  let cartItems = cartCollection.getElementsByClassName("shopping-cart-items");

  for (let x = 0; x < cartItems.length; x++) {
    let cartItem = cartItems[x];
    let cartItemQuantity = cartItem.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-input")[0];
    let quantity = cartItemQuantity.value;
    let id = cartItem.parentElement.dataset.itemId;
    let nameText = cartItem.innerText;
    let name = nameText.replace(/per lb|per item|per bundle/g, "").replace("$", "").replace(":", "");

    let cartTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("shopping-cart-number")[0].innerText;
    let price = parseFloat(cartTotal.replace("$", "")) * 100;


    items.push({
      id: id,
      quantity: quantity,
      name: name,
      price: price
    });
  }

fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    id: 1,
    quantity: 2,
    name: "test",
    price: 500})
  }).then(function(res) {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return res.json().then(function(json) {
        Promise.reject(json)
      });
    }
  }).then(({url}) => {
    console.log();
    window.location = url;
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.error("Error: " + e.error)
  });
});
```

Sever side JS

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      mode: 'payment',
      line_items: req.body.items.map(function(item) {
        return {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            product_data: {
              name: item.name
            },
            unit_amount: item.price
          },
          quantity: item.quantity
        }
      }),
      success_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/success.ejs`,
      cancel_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/cancel.ejs`
    })
    res.json({
      url: session.url
    })
    res.redirect(303, session.url)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: e.message
    })
  }
});

app.get("/success", function(req, res) {
  res.render('success');
});

app.get("/cancel", function(req, res) {
  res.render('cancel');
});
```

Server Side dependencies

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');



const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

EDIT: included my entire client side code for the checkout button. I originally left it out due to the code not being called anymore as I try to resolve the undefined issue. However, I got a few comments mentioning that items was not defined so I decided to add this in for clarity.

items is an empty array that has has objects pushed into it according to what ids were left in the shopping cart.

Comment: I think that `req.body.items` is undefined, since you are not passing `items` inside your body.
So, probably you need to pass `JSON.stringify({items:[{id:1, quantity: 2, ...}]})`

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks for the input, but the same error came up.

Comment: debug on the serverside and look at what the body is. As already mentioned, you are trying to read items and there is no where in your object that has items.

Comment: I read the body in my terminal and it came out as [object object]. However when i tried to index those objects it ran back undefined.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> The Promise returned from fetch() **won’t reject** on HTTP error
> status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, as soon as
> the server responds with headers, the Promise will resolve normally
> (with the ok property of the response set to false if the response
> isn’t in the range 200–299), and it will only reject on network
> failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

So what's happening here is that you're getting an error 500, so property `res.ok` is set to false, then it's not going through the conditional hence it's going to this part

```
      return res.json().then(function(json) {
        Promise.reject(json)
      });
```

but you're not returning `Promise.reject(json)` because you're using an anonymous function, not an arrow function so you're returning undefinded, you must explicitly return the promise like this

```
      return res.json().then(function(json) {
        return Promise.reject(json)
      });
```

^ Same goes for every anonymous function (you must return explicitly), instead of doing that I recommend you to use arrow functions and async-await

Comment: Sorry this did not seem to fix the issue.